# Stacked and Unstacked series in the same chart with jqplot?

Tags: jqplot

I would like to create a graph that has 3 series stacked and then a 4th series that is not part of the stack that runs over the top of the stacked series.

Is this possible in jqplot? the documentation has the stacking option global to the graph and separate from the series options.

Comment: Ok, just noticed that the options document says it is out of date at the top.  There is a "disableStack" option for a series listed in the Series API. that does the trick.